# How to Calling C# Base Class Default Construtor From Derived Class

Tags: c#

Hi i am novice to c# programming and try to learn it form a website  which is called tutlane.com . today i am going to practice this code but it shown error , i want to access base class default constructor from the derived class but it shown an error . so please help me to find out the error in the following code:

```
using System;

namespace Tutlane
{
    // Base Class
    public class BaseClass
    {
        // Variable 
        public string name = "ZAHID";
        public string location = "BD";
        public int age = 33;
        public string SomeText = "This is a Base Class Field OR Variable";

        //Base class Default Constructor
        public BaseClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base Class Default Constructor Called.");
        }
        //Base Class Parmeterized Construtor
        public BaseClass(string a, string b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", a);
            Console.WriteLine("Location: {0}", b);
        }

        //Method 
        public virtual void GetInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am a Base Class Method");
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", name);
            Console.WriteLine("Location: {0}", location);
        }
    }

    // Derived Class
    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        //Calling Base Class Default Construtor 
        public DerivedClass : base()
          {
          }
    // Calling Base Class Parameterized Construtor
    public DerivedClass(string x, string y) : base(x, y)
    {
    }

    //Method
    public override void GetInfo()
    {
        base.GetInfo();
        Console.WriteLine("I am a Derived Class Method");
        //Accessing Base Class Properties 
        Console.WriteLine("Accessing Base Class Field: {0}", base.SomeText);
    }
}

//Main Entry Point Class
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DerivedClass drbd_obj = new DerivedClass();
        DerivedClass drbd_obj1 = new DerivedClass("SHAKIL", "DHK");
        // drbd_obj.GetInfo();
        // BaseClass b = new BaseClass();
        //b.GetInfo();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Cannot Compile the code.Error message Shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the parentheses on the derived class' default constructor:

```
public DerivedClass() : base()
```

Comment: Thank You @Joe Sewell . The problem is Solve, You are really Helpful